# React three fiber load a list of GLTF models after an async API fetch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gltf, react-three-fiber

I have a wrapper component where I first get a list of URLs and then map over them and want load an GLTF for each of them:

AllModels.tsx:

```
export const AllModels = ({ ...props }: any) => {
    const { rotation, position } = props;
    const initialRef: any = null;
    const [modelPaths, setModelPaths] = useState(initialRef);

    const getMyData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            "http://listOfPaths.com/list.json" // ["http:...", "http://...",..]
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setModelPaths(data);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getMyData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {modelPaths &&
                modelPaths.map((value: any, index: any) => (
                    <Model key={`${index}-${value}`} path={value}></Model>
                ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

Model.tsx:

```
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export const Model = async ({ ...props }: any) => {
    const { scale, rotation, position, path } = props;

    const model = useGLTF(path);
    const scene = model.scene;
    return (
        <primitive
            castShadow
            receiveShadow
            scale={scale}
            rotation={rotation}
            position={position}
            object={scene}
        />
    );
};
```

Main.tsx:

```
    <Canvas>
            <ambientLight />
            <AllModels position={[0, 0, 0]} />
        </Canvas>
```

I tried like everything.. I get everytime a different error.. still can't undertand why people are using typescript for such things.

Error1:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type
> 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key in AllModels.tsx:
>
> <Model key={`${index}-${value}`} path={value}/>

Error2:

> Property 'scene' does not exist on type '(GLTF & ObjectMap) | (GLTF &
> ObjectMap)[]'.   Property 'scene' does not exist on type '(GLTF &
> ObjectMap)[]'.
>
> 8  const scene = model.scene;

Error3:

> 'Model' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type
> 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key 27      <Model
> key={`${index}-${value}`} path={value}/>

Comment: Remove `async` from `export const Model = async ({ ...props }: any) => {`

Comment: People are using typescript because it shows errors that you made.

Comment: no that async in model didn't change anything. But I got a working solution. Maybe I'll post it as the answer.